# Alternative to 'tensorflow.contrib' with tensorflow=2.0.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am using TensorFlow version=2.0.0, python version=3.7.9 and I was trying to import the following:

```
import tensorflow.contrib.layers as layers
```

I get this error:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'
```

As I read in this [thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31350#issuecomment-518749548), `tensorflow.contrib` doesn't exist in 2.0. Does anyone know an alternative to it? I am trying to upgrade my code from 1.0 to 2.0 as I don't want to use tf 1.0. I am using this package to build up a RNN cell.

Answer (score 1):

`tf.contrib` is deprecated in Tensorflow 2.x.

Replace `import tensorflow.contrib.layers as layers`

with

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import RNN
```